# How can I automate posting on Squarespace so that a new video stored on any other site is added as a blog post each day?

Tags: video, squarespace

I am trying to build a website for a non-profit that will post one new short video every day. The videos will have all been recorded at the beginning of the week, but I would like to automate the posting so the director doesn't have to log on each day and create the post. I was thinking of connecting Squarespace to Vimeo or Dropbox or Youtube with IFTTT or Zapier, but I can't find anything that works.

I don't need help picking a video hosting service, any will do. I need a way to schedule and automate posting videos on a Squarespace website.

Does anyone know how to do this?